# HANA: How to add a unique contraint on a column that is already indexed?

Tags: sql, indexing, unique, hana

Having the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    cryptid varchar(255) 
);
CREATE INDEX cryptid_index ON test_table (cryptid);
```

I am trying to a unique contraint to the column.

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD constraint crypid_unique_contraint UNIQUE(cryptid);
```

But this runs into an error:

```
Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE test_table ADD constraint crypid_unique_contraint ...'
Error: (dberror) [261]: invalid index name: column list already indexed
```

I can understand that the column is already indexed because I have created the index by myself. But I want the column to be unique. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wow!  I am not aware of any other database that has this limitation.  Your only option might be to drop your manual index and recreate it as a unique index (or constraint).

Comment: What version of HANA is this? And does this occur for both row and column tables?

Comment: @LarsBr. The version is 2.00.046.00.1581451565. I am not aware of what a row-table is. Will it make a difference if it will work for row-tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This might be a possibility. But suddenly because somebody messed up the permission right we cant DROP anything on our production system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an undocumented limitation in the current HANA versions.

The only way to create a unique constraint on this column is to first drop the single-column index present on this column.

I would consider the fact that this is not documented a (docu-)bug. However, the fact that existing indexes cannot be generally reused for uniqueness checks is not.
Single-column indexes in HANA's column store (which is what you use by default)  tables are **not** B-tree indexes. Instead, these are inverted indexes into the column store structure of the **main store**-part of a column store table column.
These inverted structures cannot be checked for duplicates in the current transactional context as easily as B-tree indexes could.

This, I believe, is the reason for
a) implementing the uniqueness check only on a specific index implementation in the column store,
and
b) making the system behavior (not allowing the "conversion" of an existing index into a unique index) consistent across all table types.

As a general comment: for column store tables the benefit of single-column indexes for lookup/point-read scenarios is very often not worth the additional storage & compute resource consumption. This type of index practically **doubles** the memory requirement for the indexed column. So the speed-up in looking up a specific value should be worthwhile this additional permanent resource consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the documentation on [`INDEXES`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20a7044375191014a939f50ae14306f7.html) system view. They listed this index types:

> Type of row store indexes: BTREE, BTREE_UNIQUE, CPBTREE, and CPBTREE_UNIQUE.

"Simple" index and unique index are a different index types at a build time, so there's no way to change it after the index was declared.
In other databases when you add `unique` constraint, it creates a new unique index (like in T-SQL or MySQL or Postgers) or reuses current index with this column (as in Oracle). But HANA doesn't allow you to create ether additional index on the same column (due to unknown reason, I didn't find it documented) or enforce constraint using existing index (due to poor implementation of mixture of uniqueness and index type).

The only way to go is to drop existing index and create it as unique (it is equivalent to unique constraint from the metadata point of view) from scratch, which you cannot due to authorizations. Sad but...